# Need to grab a URL 3 levels back

Tags: javascript, url

I'm trying to link an image on several different sites from a master, and I need to go 3 levels back. The URL i'm working with is: https://www.apsnet.org/meetings/annual/planthealth2020/hotel-travel/Pages/default.aspx and I need to go back to "planthealth2020"

I have Javascript from old projects that go 2 levels here:

onclick="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0,3).join('/')"

but i need to add one more level, but i'm not using a href="../../../" because if I'm on the homepage of this site (planthealth2020) I don't want a user to click on the image and get taken back an additional 3 levels.I don't know anything about javascipt. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `onclick`. If you have JS work to do, do that exclusively on the JS site by finding your image (using querySelector or getElementById or any other element selection method) and then use `.addEventListener("click", event => { ... });`. Except in this case, you don't even need that: wrap your image in an `<a href="...">` instead, and go up 3 times by using an href that starts with `../../../` because that's how URLs work. Let the browser do what it does when it gets relative URLs. Finally, javascript is not java. They are completely different programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using a link (an `a` tag). In the `href` attribute, `../` means 'go one level back'. The link below will therefore send you three levels back, from wherever you currently are:

```html
<a href="../../../">Click here to go 3 levels back.</a>
```

I don't see why it would be necessary to use an `onclick` attribute with javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using javascript for this at all? What you're describing is literally what HTML is designed to do without any outside help, using [relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL):

```
<a href="../../../" title="back to plant health 2020">
  <img src="whatever.jpg">
</a>
```

Done. If you need a navigational link, that's literally what `<a>` is for. And if you need to "go up X levels", that's literally what relative URLs are for. It might be time to shelve this work for a few hours and read through [a refresher on what HTML is for and what it can do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn).